# CKEditor from CDN trying to load theme from local files..?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor 4.8 from a CDN for our company, but it appears to be trying to load the theme files from the local directory of the website rather than from the CDN. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide config.js and the JS line that fetches CKEditor from CDN?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by theme you mean editor skin. If that is the case then CKEditor CDN by default fetches its skin from CDN.

If your editor is trying to get the skin from local resources then most likely you have [config.skin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-skin) setting defined in your CKEditor instance configuration or inside `config.js`.

Once this setting is removed, editor will fetch the default skin from CDN

**NOTE:** If you are trying to use some custom skin then please note that CDN only provides the default one and there is no other way to get the custom skin but from local resources.

Please also see: http://cdn.ckeditor.com/.